# Bootstrap datetime picker time is not showing on the edit page, why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

From the Mysql database I am getting this value:

Variable `$pickup` value is:

Array ( [0] => 01:00 PM [1] => 01:00 AM [2] => 01:00 PM [3] => 01:00 PM )

now I am showing it this way:

```
<?php foreach($noOfAdult as $key => $valu) { ?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Start Time</label>
         <input type="text" name="startTime" class="form-control addTime start_time" placeholder="Start Time" value="<?php echo $pickup[$key]; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" class="set_timestart set_start_time" name="timestart[]" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>End Time</label>
         <input type="text" name="endTime" class="form-control addTime end_time" placeholder="End Time">
         <input type="hidden" class="set_timeend set_end_time" name="timeend[]" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Javascript code I used:**

```
$(function () {
   $('.addTime').datetimepicker({
      minDate: new Date(),
      format: 'hh:mm A',        
   });
});
```

But unfortunately, time is not showing on the value!!!

Do you know why and how can I show the time which I get from the `$variable`?